# How to display the content of a combo box in a standalone div in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

So, what I am trying to do is create a combo box, add an "on click" event to it and then display the values of that combo box in a standalone div (in HTML).

I tried different things and this is the one that I am stuck on atm. Should I try something different or I am missing something here? Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="view"><p></p></div>  
<select name="heroes" id="heroes">  
  <option value="mario">Mario</option>
  <option value="sonic">Sonic</option>
  <option value="link">Link</option>
  <option value="crash">Crash Bandicoot</option> 
</select>
        

<script>
    document.getElementById("heroes").addEventListener("click" function() {
        var combo = document.getElementById("heroes");
        var i = combo.selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById("view").firstChild.innerHTML = combo.options[i].text;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot a comma between `addEventListener` arguments.

```js
document.getElementById("heroes").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var combo = document.getElementById("heroes");
    var i = combo.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("view").firstChild.innerHTML = combo.options[i].text;
});
```

```html
<div id="view"><p></p></div>
<select name="heroes" id="heroes">
  <option value="mario">Mario</option>
  <option value="sonic">Sonic</option>
  <option value="link">Link</option>
  <option value="crash">Crash Bandicoot</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your function a little and use the "change" event, because that's more likely what you want. Take a look at this:

```js
document.getElementById("heroes").addEventListener("change", function() {
    let name = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("view").firstChild.innerHTML = name;
});
```

```html
<div id="view"><p></p></div>   
<select name="heroes" id="heroes">
  <option value="none">Please select...</option>
  <option value="mario">Mario</option>
  <option value="sonic">Sonic</option>
  <option value="link">Link</option>
  <option value="crash">Crash Bandicoot</option> 
 </select>
```

Comment: could you please also accept, if this answer was useful?